# Help needed to calculate the derivative of $\int_0^t \cos(x^2) d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

I'm currently working on a calculus problem and I could use some help. The question is to find the value of $F^{\prime}(\sqrt{\pi})$ if $F(t)=\int_0^t \cos \left(x^2\right) d x$.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem since the function inside the integral involves the cosine function with an argument of $x^2$. I know that the derivative of an integral involves the function being integrated, but I'm not sure how to apply that here.

If anyone could provide some guidance on how to approach this problem or any relevant formulas that I should be using, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Find derivative of the integral then plug in the argument value.

Comment: Review the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Answer (score 8):

The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that the derivative of
$
F(t)= \int_0^t \cos(x^2) \,dx
$
is given by $F'(t)=\cos (t^2)$. So, you simply have that $F'(\sqrt{\pi}) = \cos (\pi) = -1.$

Comment: It should be said that this function is classicaly known as a [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a problem like this it is helpful to define a function to be your integrand.

In this case I would solve it by defining $g(x) = \cos{x^2}$. Therefore: $$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}{g(x)}=G(t)-G(0)$$ by the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and $$F’=\frac{d}{dt} F(t)= \frac{d}{dt} (G(t) - G(0)) = g(t)$$ (Note: $G$ is the indefinite integral of $g$, and the constant of integration disappears when taking the derivative.)

Finally plugging in out value for $F’(x)$ we obtain $F’(\sqrt{\pi})=g(\sqrt{\pi})=\cos{\sqrt{\pi}^2}=\cos{\pi}=-1$

Comment: Just because we can write out G explicitly doesn’t mean it isn’t useful. It is simply a place hold for the $\int{g(x)}dx$ which goes away when solving for $F’(\sqrt{\pi})$ which was the original goal.

Comment: @AnneBauval I like to use $G(x) because it makes the logic far more clear, in my opinion, and if the bounds are functions the chain rule pops out with more ease. If it doesn’t help you you can ignore it.

Comment: If you're going to use $G$, you should at least explicitly define it instead of making the OP guess from context - especially when it's clear that the questioner is still getting their minds around the basics.

Comment: Fair enough I guess. I always thought of $G$ as standard notation, and my answer pops right out of the 2nd FTC, but maybe making that explicit would have eased understanding.

Comment: @EzTheBoss2 - You can always go back and edit your answer at any time. If you add it now, it might make it easier to understand for future readers. I can tell you that when I read it, my mind said "wait, what's $G$?", and then I spent some time trying to see where you defined it, figured you hadn't, and then intuited what it must be from context. It not being defined definitely made your answer harder to understand for me.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC thank you for your feedback! I always thought that that was relatively standard but I also get that then original problem statement doesn’t use that notation so I can see why it was confusing. I have also added more explicit statements of my reasoning to hopefully help future readers.

Comment: Yeah, one of the things about math.se is that we're not all in the same class together, so we don't necessarily share the same notations and conventions. I'm often a lot more explicit when I'm posting something here. Thanks for putting the extra polish on your answer.